# Тире после условного придаточного с союзом "если"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, тире, сложное-предложение

1. *Так что(,) если в бизнесе разбираешься и хотя бы один язык на достойном уровне(,) — можешь уже идти.*

Мне кажется, не нужно ставить ни одну, ни другую запятую: тире заменяет пропущенную часть составного союза "если..., то...".

Пользуясь случаем, также хочу спросить: что за мода пошла после условного придаточного с союзом "если" ставить тире, если главное предложение в повелительном наклонении?

2. *Если ты хочешь удивить своих гостей горячей закуской — ознакомься с моим рецептом.*

Answer (score 2):

Возможны варианты. Если тире не подлежит сомнению, хотя оно как раз факультативно:

*Так что, если в бизнесе разбираешься и хотя бы один язык на достойном уровне, — можешь уже идти.* Запятые на месте по правилу: если изъятие придаточного предложения не требует перестройки главного, нет второй части союза то. Тире интонационное, чтобы подчеркнуть сказуемое в главном.

*Так что если в бизнесе разбираешься и хотя бы один язык на достойном уровне — можешь уже идти.* Можно объяснить отсутствие запятой смысловым отнесением союза так что к придаточному.

Похоже на примечание у Розенталя: В предложениях типа *Он давно уже уехал, и где он теперь, я не знаю* запятая после союза и не ставится. Здесь И относится к придаточному.

По правилам запятая обычно не ставится между присоединительным союзом (после точки) и союзом подчинительным, например: И кто вы такой, я знаю; А зачем это говорится, мне непонятно. Возможность постановки запятой после других присоединительных союзов связана с интонационно-смысловым выделением придаточного предложения, например: Однако, если вы так настаиваете на своём предложении, я готов его принять. Но у нас первый союз не присоединительный, а подчинительный следствия, поэтому запятая желательна.

Или без тире:

*Так что, если в бизнесе разбираешься и хотя бы один язык на достойном уровне, можешь уже идти.* Это соответствует общим правилам.

```
 что за мода пошла после условного придаточного с союзом "если" ставить
тире, если главное предложение в повелительном наклонении?
```

Это не мода, это соответствует правилам:

§ 111. Тире в сложноподчиненном предложении
При интонационном подчеркивании придаточные изъяснительные (дополнительные и подлежащные), реже условные и уступительные , стоящие впереди главного предложения, могут отделяться от него не запятой, а тире, например: Буде спросит кто о чём – молчи… (Пушкин); Как он добрался сюда – уж этого никак не мог он понять (Гоголь); Что она натура честная – это мне ясно… (Тургенев); Пускай, как хотят, тиранят, пускай хоть кожу с живой снимут – я воли своей не отдам (Салтыков-Щедрин).

И это не зависит от наклонения глагола-сказуемого в главном.

Comment: А я вот никогда не понимал, как в некоторых случаях при отсутствии второй части составного союза можно  не ставить запятую перед придаточным. "Он давно уже уехал, и где он теперь, я не знаю". "И кто вы такой, я знаю". "А зачем это говорится, мне непонятно". Вот этих примерах ещё понятно: союз действительно скорее относится к придаточному.

Comment: Но вот в примере: "Поэтому прежде чем изменить орбиту астероида, его параметры надо очень точно измерить" — очевидно же, что "поэтому" относится к главному предложению: "Поэтому его параметры надо очень точно измерить". "Поэтому прежде чем давать секретарю поручение об уничтожении документов, нужно удостовериться, что их сроки хранения истекли", — здесь так же: "Поэтому нужно удостовериться, что их сроки хранения истекли".

Comment: Кстати: "Присоединительное значение могут приобретать подчинительные союзы и союзные местоименно-наречные слова: если, потому что, ибо, что, который, как, как (бы), когда и др." (http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-037.htm)